# SQLAlchemy (Postgres) ARRAY vs JSON for list of integers

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I want to store a list of integers in a Column with SQLAlchemy (using Postgres).

Am I better off using ARRAY or JSON? My guess is ARRAY would have better performance in this case, but I don't see anything online confirming that.

Additional question: What if I want the integers to be unique?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PostgreSQL collects statistics on array membership for PostgreSQL arrays, but not for JSON arrays.  This often leads to much better performance.  Plus PostgreSQL arrays are typed, which seems like a benefit for your case.

> Additional question: What if I want the integers to be unique?

Can you expand on that?  You want it to throw an error if you try to add a second copy of any one element?  Silently ignore the addition?  (Although neither case has in-place additions, it is really an assignment of the new array/JSONB which has happens to have one more element than the old one).

Comment: By unique, I mean I want it to act more like a set than an list. Any integer in the set should only appear once. Silently ignoring the addition would be fine.